# Как можно стримить с одного iphone на другой?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, iphone

Как можно реалтайм стримить с одного айфона на другой айфон без сервера, в одной wi-fi сети? Есть ли для этого библиотеки или в какую сторону для этого надо смотреть?

Comment: Напиши в гугле: "video streaming from iphone to iphone directly. Swift, Objective-C". Я бы помог и более конкретно, но нет времени.

Comment: Нигде не увидел, чтобы без сервера работалось(

Comment: Не разбираюсь и не знаю, но что насчёт передачи сырых данных при помощи сокетов? Просто мысль вслух